# Are there any visual phrases similar to "struck a chord"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, language-formation

I've noticed there are a number of idioms for familiarity that refer to audio phenomena (e.g. "strikes a chord", "rings a bell", etc), but try as I might I can't think of any vision based phrases. It seems a bit strange to say something like "that picture rings a bell", so I wonder if there are any similar idioms that don't reference sound?

I looked up a list of the most common english idioms, and they all seem to be either sound related (e.g. "barking up the wrong tree"), or about a specific object or action (e.g. "take with a grain of salt", keywords: "take" and "salt"). None of them involved seeing or images.

Am I just bad at thinking of things, or does english really show an aversion to vision-based figures of speech? If so, what factors influence the types of idioms adopted?

And what (if any) is the visual alternative to "strikes a chord"?

Comment: Would you consider "touched a nerve" to be visual or tactile?

Comment: @SvenYargs tactile, because you "touch", of course - how would it be visual?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a visual "translation" of *struck a chord*, or just a list of vision-related idioms? The former is an interesting question, and it might be useful to highlight that part in your question; the latter is also interesting, but off-topic here (list questions aren't a great fit for the SE model). In re "touched a nerve": Presumably because when light "touches" the eye the visual information is transmitted to the brain via the optic nerve.

Answer (score 6):

There is the idiom *see the light* meaning to gain an understanding of something.  Per Wiktionary:

> ***[see the light](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/see_the_light)***
>
> 1. (*idiomatic, religious*) To undergo a spiritual conversion.
>
>    *Once I was lost in darkness, but now I have seen the light.*
> 2. (*idiomatic*) To gain an understanding of something previously not understood, especially in a sudden insight.
>
>    *Finally, near the end of the meeting, John saw the light and withdrew his objections.*
> 3. (*idiomatic*) To come into the world or to public notice.
>
>    *His book never saw the light.*

There is also *sight for sore eyes* which Wiktionary defines as:

> ***[sight for sore eyes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sight_for_sore_eyes)*** (*plural* sights for sore eyes)
>
> 1. (*idiomatic*) A pleasing sight; something that is beautiful to look at.
>
>    *When the fog lifted, the view of the glacier was a sight for sore eyes.*

It is often used to describe something or someone you haven't seen in a long time that you're happy to see (e.g., *Sally, it's been too long; you sure are a sight for sore eyes!*) or some object that is especially pleasurable in light of recent experiences (e.g., *after the slop they fed us in boot camp, the hamburger and fries was a sight for sore eyes*.)

And that reminds me of another:  *in light of*.  Per Wiktionary:

> ***[in light of](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_light_of)***
>
> 1. (*idiomatic, Australia, Canada, US*) given, considering
>
>    *In light of the frequent kidnappings in Iraq, do you suppose someone could invent a small tracking device that could be woven onto clothing and hard to find on it so that when someone gets kidnapped, the tracking devices could pin down their location?*

There are also *point of view* (Wiktionary):

> ***[point of view](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/point_of_view)*** (*plural* points of view)
>
> 1. A position from which something is seen; outlook; standpoint.
>
>    *From an economist's point of view, business is all about money.*
> 2. An attitude, opinion, or set of beliefs.
>
>    *His point of view is that there is only one true religion.*
> 3. (*literary theory*) The perspective from which a narrative is related.
>
>    *The storyline in the film “The Usual Suspects” is presented from the point of view of an unreliable narrator.*

*bird's eye view* (Wiktionary):

> ***[bird's-eye view](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bird%27s-eye_view)*** (*plural* bird's-eye views)
>
> 1. (*idiomatic*) The view from directly or high above.
>
>    *Looking down from the seventh floor balcony gave them a bird's-eye view of the street below.*
> 2. (*by extension*) A general overview or summary of a topic.

and *hidden in plain sight* (Wiktionary):

> ***[hidden in plain sight](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hidden_in_plain_sight)*** (*not comparable*)
>
> 1. (*idiomatic*) Seemingly hidden, but actually not hidden and easy to find.

Comment: [illuminate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illuminate) - to make clear : elucidate.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously Anglophones have a *lot* of metaphoric usages relating to vision. They're so common we barely notice the metaphoric aspect of, say, *Your plan **looks** like a bad idea to me. I don't **see** how it could ever work.*

For idiomatic usages combining vision *and* "familiarity"...

> *[If] You've **seen** one, you've seen 'em all.* [(1430 written instances)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22seen%20one%2C%20you%27ve%20seen%20%27em%20all%22)
>    *Been there, **seen** it, got the T-shirt.* [(84 instances)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Been%20there%2C%20seen%20it%2C%20got%20the%20T-shirt%22)
>   *He was a familiar **sight** in [the places he frequented].* [(3580 instances)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he%20was%20a%20familiar%20sight%20in%22)

...I particularly like this as an example of a "mixed metaphor" usage that would normally pass unnoticed by the average reader...

> [*His critique was visionary and pioneering, and I **see echoes** of his writings in many of my subsequent papers.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%20see%20echoes%20of%20his%22)

Answer (score 1):

**easy on the eye** [TDF](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/easy+on+the+eye)

> Attractive. The phrase is more frequently seen as "easy on the eyes."

Comment: And *beauty is in the eye of the beholder.*

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the verb "eyeball" as in, "Those sticks look a little long, you think he *eyeballed* the measurements?" The OED defines it as:

> [**eyeball**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/67302?rskey=Molr0y&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid), v.
>
> To make a visual inspection or assessment of; to measure by sight alone, without the use of an instrument or other guide; to estimate by eye.

You also have "I see what you did there." Per the OED:

> [**(do you) see what I did there?, I see what you did there**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/174749?rskey=8PZCeK&result=1#eid1178226020), and variants: used humorously and ironically to draw attention to a joke, pun, etc.

And lastly, "eye candy." Again from the OED:

> [**eye candy**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/67296?redirectedFrom=eye+candy#eid4903196) n. colloq. something (originally a feature of a television programme) considered as conferring visual appeal, esp. if also thought to lack substance; (later also) an exceptionally attractive person

Answer (score 0):

> [in focus](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+into+focus) 3. Fig. [of problems, solutions, appraisals of people or
>   things] perceived or understood clearly. (*Typically: be ~; get [into]
>   ~; get something [into] ~.) Now that things are in focus, I feel
>   better about the world.
>
> [eagle eye](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/eagle-eye) a person who has sharp vision or who maintains a keen
>   watchfulness; alert watchfullness